# ocLazyLoad controller dependency data resolve issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise, resolve, oclazyload

I have a situation where i am loading a service and controller with ocLazyLoad in angular js, which is working as expected. But, i also want to pass some data to controller by using the service which is resolved by ocLazyLoad and unfortunately i am not able to pull this off by any means. I have tried the below two approaches.

My service

```
(function () {
'use strict;'
angular.module('app')
    .service('vendorService', function (http, config) {
        return {
            create: function(model){
                return http.post(config.apiUrl + "api/vendor/", model);
            },
            update: function(id , model){
                return http.put(config.apiUrl + "api/vendor/" + id, model);
            },
            delete: function(id){
                return http.delete(config.apiUrl + "api/vendor/" + id);
            },
            get: function(id){
                return http.get(config.apiUrl+ "api/vendor/" + id);
            },
            getAll: function(){
                return http.get(config.apiUrl + "api/vendor");
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

My controller

```
(function () {
'use strict;'
angular.module('app')
    .controller('vendorsController', function (vendorService, NgTableParams, vendors) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.vendorsTable = new NgTableParams({
            count: 10
        }, {
            counts: [10, 25, 50],
            dataset: angular.copy(vendors)
        });
    });
})();
```

My config which is loaded from index.html page.

Approach 1

```
(function () {
'use strict;'
angular.module('app')
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('app.vendors', {
                url: '/vendors',
                templateUrl: 'app/main/vendors/index.html',
                controller: 'vendorsController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                resolve: {
                    deps: function ($ocLazyLoad, $injector) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                            'app/services/vendor.service.js',
                            'app/main/vendors/vendors.controller.js'
                        ])
                    },
                    vendors: function ($injector) {
                        var vendorService = $injector.get('vendorService');
                        return vendorService.getAll();
                    }
                }
            })
    });
})();
```

Approach 2

```
(function () {
'use strict;'
angular.module('app')
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('app.vendors', {
                url: '/vendors',
                templateUrl: 'app/main/vendors/index.html',
                controller: 'vendorsController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                resolve: {
                    deps: function ($ocLazyLoad, $injector) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                            'app/services/vendor.service.js',
                            'app/main/vendors/vendors.controller.js'
                        ])
                    },
                    vendors: function (vendorService) {
                        return vendorService.getAll();
                    }
                }
            })
    });
})();
```

There is no error in console as well, all the dependencies required in services e.g http service and config is pre loaded from html page itself.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: just so that you may know here in my code http is build on top of $http and  is different :)

Comment: An update, I added try catch and now getting the *Unknown Provider* error, which i don't know why because service is being loaded, if i remove the vendors resolve function it works fine :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i resolved this issue. I saw in chrome network tab that the data resolve function was called prior to actual loading of js files by ocLazyLoad, what i did was to include the ocLazyLoad resolve dependency in my controller data dependency as below

```
resolve: {
                    **deps**: function ($ocLazyLoad, $injector) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                            'app/services/vendor.service.js',
                            'app/main/vendors/vendors.controller.js'
                        ])
                    },
                    vendors: function (**deps**, $injector) {
                        debugger;
                       try {
                            var vendorService = $injector.get('vendorService');
                            return vendorService.getAll();
                       } catch (error) {
                           console.error(error);
                       }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little more of it? I ment, how do you call ocLazyLoad from your controller? were you able to load a js file from your controller?, thanks.